# Мигающий header при скроле

Tags: jquery, css

Решил сделать прилипающий `header` при скроле, при этом столкнулся с неприятным багом. Когда происходит скрол `header` начинает мигать.

Подскажите в чем проблема,и как это можно решить?

[Пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/vZzmQo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
var navPos = jQuery('nav').offset().top;
```

На

```
var navPos = jQuery('nav').position().top;
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgVgda)

Comment: Спасибо работает!  Но   обясните что не так с методом offset, почему с помощью него функция работала не корректно?

Comment: Суть в том, что в результате манипуляций с классом у вас меняется размер nav. Решение которое я предложил выше не совсем корректно: при обратном скролле верх нет плавного перехода к стандартной шапке. Выход прост: вынести определение ` var navPos = jQuery('nav').offset().top; ` вне скролла и использовать offset. Обновил пен: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgVgda?editors=1111

Comment: Еще один вопрос?Каким образом можно сделать плавный  переход при добавление классa fixed. Сейчас как можно увидеть при переходе во второе состояние header резко перекрывает контент https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/vZzmQo